# Cypress: How to log each element click to a file?

Tags: cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I created a log file in which I log there various operations during my tests.
I would also like to log any elements click I perform.
However, I don't want to add a specific log instruction before each click command, but I want it to log the click seamlessly.

I tried to overwrite the click command like this:

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite(
 'click',
 (originalFn, subject, positionOrX, y, options = {}) => {
    Logger.log('I just clicked ' + subject)
    return originalFn(subject, positionOrX, y, options);
 }
);
```

but somehow it broke my tests.

For example, I have this login command which is the first I use in the before hook:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('loginSys', (username = Cypress.env("USERNAME"), password = Cypress.env("PASSWORD")) => {

    cy.clearAllLocalStorage()

    cy.intercept('POST', '*login*').as('login')
    cy.visit(getCMUrl())
    cy.login(username, password)
    cy.wait('@login').then((interception) => {
        const token = interception.response.body.token
        Cypress.env('ACCESS_CODE', token)
    })
})
```

I receive the following error:

```
Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.

The command that returned the promise was:

> cy.type()

The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:

> cy.log()

Because Cypress commands are already promise-like, you don't need to wrap them or return your own promise.
```

This error happens as I overwrite click command.

Comment: Works ok, it's all good. Can not reproduce this one, you have any details?

Comment: @BigMo Thank you for your time. Please see my post update for details.

Answer (score 4):

The `.login()` command will have a `.type()` command in it (possibly two, user & password).

Cypress says this about [.type()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type#When-element-is-not-in-focus)

> If the element is currently not in focus, before issuing any keystrokes Cypress will first issue a `.click()` to the element to bring it into focus.

Probably explains the link between your `.click()` overwrite and the "broken" `cy.login()`.

So, when logging in the overwrite don't use `cy.log()` use the alternate [Cypress.log()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cypress-log) instead.

> Useful when writing ***your own custom commands***.

Comment: Thank you Mezi. 
I am now using
  Cypress.log({ message: text });
Now I get
   I just clicked [object Object]
in the log.
If I use 
  'I just clicked ' + JSON.stringify(subject))
I get 

Timed out retrying after 15000ms: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'HTMLInputElement'
|     property '__reactInternalInstance$cs4polkk535' -> object with constructor 'js'
--- property 'stateNode' closes the circle

Comment: That would be in your `JSON.stringify`.